# how to used nesteded serilizer i am getting attribute error

Tags: python, django

I am  getting attribute error

```
accounts app name
models.py
class AddressUser(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(Customer_create, related_name='customer_address', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True,null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True,null=True)
    house_number = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    builiding_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    block_no = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    state_choices = (
        ("Andhra Pradesh", "Andhra Pradesh"), ("Arunachal Pradesh ", "Arunachal Pradesh "), ("Assam", "Assam"),
        ("Bihar", "Bihar"), ("Chhattisgarh", "Chhattisgarh"), ("Goa", "Goa"), ("Gujarat", "Gujarat"),
        ("Haryana", "Haryana"), ("Himachal Pradesh", "Himachal Pradesh"), ("Jammu and Kashmir ", "Jammu and Kashmir "),
        ("Jharkhand", "Jharkhand"), ("Karnataka", "Karnataka"), ("Kerala", "Kerala"), ("Madhya Pradesh", "Madhya Pradesh"),
        ("Maharashtra", "Maharashtra"), ("Manipur", "Manipur"), ("Meghalaya", "Meghalaya"), ("Mizoram", "Mizoram"),
        ("Nagaland", "Nagaland"), ("Odisha", "Odisha"), ("Punjab", "Punjab"), ("Rajasthan", "Rajasthan"),
        ("Sikkim", "Sikkim"), ("Tamil Nadu", "Tamil Nadu"), ("Telangana", "Telangana"), ("Tripura", "Tripura"),
        ("Uttar Pradesh", "Uttar Pradesh"), ("Uttarakhand", "Uttarakhand"), ("West Bengal", "West Bengal"),
        ("Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands"), ("Chandigarh", "Chandigarh"),
        ("Dadra and Nagar Haveli", "Dadra and Nagar Haveli"), ("Daman and Diu", "Daman and Diu"),
        ("Lakshadweep", "Lakshadweep"), ("National Capital Territory of Delhi", "National Capital Territory of Delhi"),
        ("Puducherry", "Puducherry"))
    state = models.CharField(choices=state_choices, max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='India')
Simple app
model.py
class Customer_create(models.Model):
    #address = models.ForeignKey(AddressUser, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    customer_name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    mobile_number=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
serializers.py
class AddressSerlizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AddressUser
        fields = ('id','house_number','builiding_name','block_no', 'street', 'area', 'city', 'pincode', 'state', 'country',)
class Customer_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerlizer(many=True, allow_null=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer_create
        fields = ('id','customer_name',
                'mobile_number',
                'email',
                'address',)
    # def create(self, validated_data):
    #     """
    #     Overriding the default create method of the Model serializer.
    #     :param validated_data: data containing all the details of student
    #     :return: returns a successfully created student record
    #     """
    #     user_data = validated_data.pop('address')
    #     user = AddressSerlizer.create(AddressSerlizer(), validated_data=user_data)
    #     student, created = Customer_create.objects.create(user=user,
    #                                                     customer_name = validated_data.pop('customer_name'),
    #                                                   mobile_name=validated_data.pop('mobile_number'),
    #                                                   email=validated_data.pop('email'))
    #     return student
    def create(self, validated_data):
        address_data = validated_data.pop('address')
        # customer = Customer_create.objects.create(**validated_data)
        # AddressUser.objects.create(customer=customer, **address_data)
        # return customer
        # customer = Customer_create(customer_name = validated_data['customer_name'],
        #                            mobile_name = validated_data['mobile_number'],
        #                            email = validated_data['email']
        #                            )
        # customer.save()
        customer = Customer_create.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for i in address_data:
            AddressUser.objects.create(customer=customer, **i)
        return customer
AttributeError at /simple/customer_post
```

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `address` on serializer `Customer_serializer`.
    The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Customer_create` instance.
    Original exception text was: 'Customer_create' object has no attribute`'address'.

**

Answer (score 0):

This is because You need to specify relationship between `Customer_create` model and `AddressUser` model. *You could remove below comments from your `Customer_create` model as below*. Because DRF serializer cannot find `address` in your `Customer_create` model`s instance.

```
class Customer_create(models.Model):
    #address = models.ForeignKey(AddressUser, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    customer_name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    mobile_number=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Than run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` commands